# Reduce an array to only the User object - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreign-key-relationship, eloquent

The Route where I want to retrieve information about a User with id 6

```
Route::get('/', function() {
        echo '<pre>';
           var_dump(User::find(6)->where('person_id' == 1));
        echo '</pre>';
    });
```

It gives me:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)#176 (4) {
  ["query":protected]=>
  object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)#175 (19) {
    ["connection":protected]=>
    object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection)#178 (15) {
      ["pdo":protected]=>
      object(PDO)#177 (0) {
      }
      ["queryGrammar":protected]=>
      object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar)#192 (3) {
        ["wrapper":protected]=>
        string(4) "`%s`"
        ["selectComponents":protected]=>
        array(11) {
          [0]=>
          string(9) "aggregate"
          [1]=>
          string(7) "columns"
          [2]=>
          ...........
```

I only want the User object. The page gives me 44327 lines of text..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am concerned, you should use a function like `get()` that will return you those `User` objects.

Try :

```
$users = User::find(6)->where('person_id', 1)->get();
var_dump($users);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use primary id if you use `find()` or `findOrfail()`.

For example: consider the following `users` table

```
id name email

1  AA   aa@gmail.com
2  BB   bb@gmail.com
```

here `id` is the primary key. if you want to retrieve data for `id 1`

```
$user = User::find(1);

var_dump($user);
```

**So, you can see, your query was invalid**

Try the following instead:

```
 var_dump(User::find(6));
```

**or**

```
var_dump(User::where('person_id', 1)->first());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eloquent the where method only returns a query object instance, in that moment the framework has yet to go to the database. To accomplish this you should use a trigger method as pointed out such as get() after the query or the first() method if you expect only one result.

there are of course, methods like find() that automatically search by primary key and execute the query right away.